# ComponentDidUpdate() data from the api with new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Being new to react, I saw a similar example but they were not clearly explained and I didn't understand how to solve this problem. I have an API, the new data is posted to the API.
`ComponentDidMount()` will initiate the data from the API first time.
I went through the documentation and saw that `componentDiUpdate()` will always re-render the page if the new data is added.

This is my code so far:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    newData: [],
    dataApi: this.props.getAllData() //method that is using GET_ALL_DATA actions/reducers using fetch(get)
  }
}
// it gets the data
componentDidMount() {
  this.state.dataApi
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  this.state.dataApi.then(data => {
    if(prevProps.data != this.props.data) {
      this.setState({newData: data});
    }
  }
}
```

`ComponentDidUpdate()` errors:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

How can I fix this problem? by getting the new data from the API when someone makes a post request? Thanks

Comment: sounds like when you navigate away from a browser page your component is still trying to set a state, after the component is unmounted.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I think is the way I am doing is wrong, because the code is not  working, I cannot get the updated data from the api, by calling just this.state.dataApi

Comment: Yea, you shouldn't put a promise on your state like that, just call `getAllData()` in didMount and chain the `.then` there as well. But if this component is tied to a webpage, you need to remember that if the component unmounts you need to kill the setstate call in your promise then callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem, thanks everyone:
Solution to the problem will be:

```
this.state = {
   allData: [],
   isSubmitted: false
}

async componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
  if(this.mounted && this.state.isSubmitted){
     const allData = await this.props.getAllData();
     this.setState({isSubmitted: false,
                  allData: allData.data })
  }

componentDidMount(){ 
   this.mounted=true
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.mounted = false; 
}

functionAddDataToApi(){
   // some logic
   this.setState({isSubmitted: true})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method gets called once only when your component is rendered for the first time.

In your `constructor()`, you don't need to put a promise on your state. Instead you can remove `dataApi` and just call the method directly. In `componentDidMount()`, you'll make your API call. When the API call has finished, you can use `this.setState()`.

The `componentDidUpdate` method gets called every time one of your prop or state values gets updated. As such, it is a bad idea to update state within it as you risk infinitely looping.

```
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
           newData: [], 
      };
}

// it gets the data
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getAllData().then(data => {
        this.setState({
            newData: data,
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: ComponentDidMount() is working, I am still trying to understand how can I use componentDidUpdate(,  a short example: lets stay I get all data from the api first in a table, you add a new record(post request) the record is in the api, now without using the componentDidUpdate I have to refresh the window in order to see the record in the table, how can I fix this problem without refreshing the window?

Comment: or John, still haven't solved this problem, would you guys be able to help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hook to props change before re-render try hooking into componentWillReceiveProps. componentWillReceiveProps will update state synchronously.

also.. code in your componentDidMount will do nothing :)

```
// it gets the data
componentDidMount(){
      this.state.dataApi}
```

try to replace it with

```
// it gets the data
componentDidMount() {
    this.state.dataApi.then(data => {
        this.setState({
            newData: data,
         });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting the state asynchronously (for example, after a promise is resolved), it's important to **make sure that your component is still mounted**, otherwise, you risk setting the state on an unmounted component (which triggers the error that you are getting).

To do that, you will need to set some kind of a flag (like `this.mounted` in the below example):

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mounted = true;
}

async componentDidUpdate() {
  const data = await someAPICall();
  if (this.mounted && !_.isEqual(this.state.data, data)) { // See comment below
    this.setState({data});
  }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this.mounted = false;
}
```

Also, when comparing the old data with the new data, you'll need to perform a **deep compare** (in the example above I'm using lodash `isEqual(...)`).

A shallow compare (i.e. `this.state.data !== data`) compares the *references* of each of the objects, which are always going to be different, regardless of the actual data, and therefore will run into an **infinite loop** because `setState()` will trigger another `componentDidUpdate()` and so on.

Comment: doing your example I am getting inifinite loop.

Comment: Yes, you need some kind of a condition if you're using `componentDidUpdate()` to update the state, otherwise, it will go into an infinite loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: by writing the same code, still gets to infinite loop. should be this.props.data? instead of this.state.data?

Comment: Please read my last comment in the post, you have to do a **deep compare**

Comment: await someApiCall() (is dispatch any Promiseany) the this.state.data it returns a promise resolved which have promiseValue object: data [] type: get all data

Comment: That’s not the right way to do it. The state should not contain promises or functions, only strings/numbers/arrays/objects.

Comment: this is the code: const data = await this.props.getAllData(); if(this.mounted && this.state.data !== data) { this.setState({data})  construtor is data: []

Comment: If it’s coming as a prop, then yes - `const data = await this.props.getAllData()` but the key here is the deep comparison I.e. `deepCompare(this.state.data, data)`. You can use a library like lodash for this, or write your own function.

Comment: I understand what you mean to do a comparison but I am very new to react, do you have a more explained example? of how to do comparison between data from the api and old data? thanks

Comment: Yoav it is possible to use componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated, so avoid using it. You should use `conponentDidUpdate` instead. Can you elaborate on what it is exactly that you are unable to achieve?